# How to intercept and modify a SOAP message before the security header is validated by WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap, ws-security

A client calls my service with some WS-Security header values that are not supported by WCF (PasswordDigest), so I get a "System.ServiceModel.FaultException: An error occurred when verifying security for the message." exception.

How to intercept the message and modify it before WCF validates the security header? I tried intercepting the incoming message using Message Interceptors but the message is intercepted after the validation of the security header.